# Test analysis - repeated measures

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, repeated-measures, friedman-test

I lack the experience and can't find an answer anywhere at the moment.

The situation is as follows:
I would like to test a new device measuring the heart rate of a patient. For this, I have observed roughly 30 patients undergoing a clinical procedure continously. Because I am only interested in certain values, I extracted data for roughly 20 points of time for each patient. Now, for some of those points I could not gather information for every patient.

The data that I collected has then been assigned a certain quality label (poor, medium, exccellent). Now I combined some of the points, e.g. time points 1-3 are before the clinical procedure (phase 1), 4-14 are during the clinical procedure (phase 2), 15-20 are afterwards (phase 3). In conclusion, when I calculate frequency with, data is as follows:

Phase 1: 20 excellent, 20x medium, 10 poor
Phase 2: 40 excellent, 10 medium, 30 poor
Phase 3: 5 excellent, 3 medium, 40 poor

Note that the amount differs because not all data was collected (for example, phase 2 was during the clinical procedure which took a differing amount of time for each patient).

I would now **like to answer the following question statistically: Is there a difference in quality between Phase 1, 2 and 3?**

The null hypothesis would be that
quality phase 1 = quality phase 2 = quality phase 3.

I am not completely sure which test to choose. I guess it has to be a non parametric test because of the **repeated measures**. Since the **dependent variable "quality" is ordinal**, I would like to use the Friedman test. Is that correct and can I use the test even though I have a differing amount of samples in each phase?

How do I implement the test in SPSS, combining my samples (e.g. combining points of time 1-3 as phase 1)?